# dose select2 support custom data-attr mapping

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I am filling select2 input remotely by ajax

```
$.getJSON(DataLink, function (data) {
        $('#select').select2({
            data: $.map(data.data, function (obj) {
                return {id: obj.id, text: obj.name};

            })
        });
    });
```

I need to insert a custom attribute to the option from the remote data, but since "data" option defines only id for option value and text for option text, how to map third data obj as data-attribute?

```
 return {id: obj.id, text: obj.name,flagship:obj.flagship_id};
```

Comment: have you tried `templateResult` config

Comment: @shivamGupta yes but i am not able to access object.id outside the loop of mapping

Comment: http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2#usage-advanced found this link might help you

Comment: https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widgets/issues/247 also look into it